# How to pending blank lines to fill full page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I made bookmarks in my index,

but the content for the last bookmark is too short

So the header of `Projects` will be on the GREEN PROJECT position,

It looks very ugly is there any way to auto padding 
 or something

to fill the section into a whole page length ?

```
          / Controls
          %a.left.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "prev", href: "#carousel-example-generic"}
            %span.fa.fa-chevron-left
          %a.right.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "next", href: "#carousel-example-generic"}
            %span.fa.fa-chevron-right
  %span#ptable
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
%br
```

[image]

Without padding 
 , the layout will be that way.
[image]

Comment: Not clear about your requirement. Seems like you need a good IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your %br. And give padding 2px 3px.. The padding value must be differ to your form.

Comment: Be more specific , please. where should those padding be.

Comment: First you remove your %br, and then give the padding value at the same line